# Limit of a complex valued function in polar coords

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \dfrac{z}{z+\mid z\mid}$. We have to find the limit as $z \to 0$.

In polar coordinates, we have $f = \dfrac{re^{i\theta}}{re^{i\theta} +r}=\dfrac{e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}+1}$

As this form is not dependent on $r$, what can we conclude about the limit as $r \to 0$?

Comment: You can conclude that the limit does not exist. Because you get different values for different $\theta$s

Answer (score 1):

Putting $\;z=x+iy\;,\;\;x,\,y\in\Bbb R\;$, we have:

$$x=y:\;\implies\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x(1+i)}{x(1+i)+\sqrt2\,|x|}=\begin{cases}\frac{1+i}{1+i+\sqrt2}\,,&x>0\\{}\\\frac{1+i}{1+i-\sqrt2}\,&x<0\end{cases}$$

and thus *the limit* doesn't exist.